# How to highlight a single cell in Tabulator when data changes

Tags: jquery, tabulator

I'm trying to use the jQuery .effect() function to highlight changes in my Tabulator data as it is refreshed from the server.

I am still using Tabulator 3.5 so thought jQuery .effect() would be the simplest approach. It is not mandatory to use, as long as the desired result is achieved.

I've tried to set up a simple counter in the table where the value is highlighted as it changes (no ajax yet), but can only get the whole row, column, or row and column to be highlighted, and not the cell specifically.

```
var i = 1;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(i<=5){
        var id = 12345;
        var row = $("#live-table").tabulator("getRow", id);

        // Manually updated for now - from ajax later
        $("#live-table").tabulator("updateData", [{playerId:id, blah:i}]);

        // Successfully highlights the col on value change
        $("#live-table .tabulator-cell[tabulator-field=blah]").effect( "highlight",{color: '#329cff'},3000);
        // Successfully highlights the row on value change
        $("#live-table .tabulator-row:nth-child(1)").effect( "highlight",{color: '#329cff'},3000);

        i++;
    }else{
        clearInterval(timer);
        console.log("cleared");
    }
}, 3000);
```

I've tried combining the two lines into one .effect() with varying syntax to highlight only the cell, but this has not been successful.

I've searched the docs for a callback that I could use (like `dataEdited` etc), but haven't been able to find one as yet. If there was something available that detected the change in CELL value it would be much simpler going forward, as there will be some processing server side to actually find the changed data using my current approach - specifically a row number and col name...

**UPDATE:** [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vapozmcf/1/) of what I was trying to acheive.

Comment: Have you tried using the `rowUpdated` callback? More infos here : http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/callbacks#row

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll be looking into the ```rowUpdated``` and other similar callbacks to know when to highlight the changes, however this question was specifically about the highlighting of a single cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem using the following code. The counter in the timer will be replaced by a longer interval and a query of the database when fully implemented, and is obviously not necessary to achieve the highlighting of changed data. NOTE: Tabulator version 3.5...

```
var i = 1;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(i<=5){
        var id = 12345;
        var row = $("#live-table").tabulator("getRow", id);
        var cell = row.getCell("blah");
        // Manually updated for now - from ajax DB query later
        $("#live-table").tabulator("updateData", [{playerId:id, blah:i}]);
        cell.getElement().effect( "highlight",{color: '#329cff'},3000);
        i++;
    }else{
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 3000);
```

**UPDATE:** [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vapozmcf/1/) of what I was trying to acheive.

Comment: Also @dota2pro, thanks for the setInterval link. It looks like I'll be using it correctly according to that answer you pointed me to as it states:  _if you are using it to do something that should be done every x milliseconds, well you are using it correctly_... Since I'm using it every x ms to update my table data and highlight any changes, it seems I'll have your blessing to proceed after all. Thanks again!

Comment: If you are using 3.5 when 4.2.7 is out, I think **setInterval** is the best way to go ahead, you don't need my **helpful** comments

Comment: Thanks! Changing everything to work without the original jQuerey dependencies is in the too hard/no time basket for now... That is the reason for sticking with the old version.

Comment: thats my point exactly setinterval code isn't portable. where as callbacks in the Tabulator object are

Comment: I hadn't used setInterval until 3 days ago, and it was still not worth my time to update to v4+ before that... How do you propose making the table data refresh at a certain, predefined, interval then?

Comment: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/reactivity#reactive-data  reactiveData:true watches for data changes automatically and instantly

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this simple approach inside your tabulator callbacks. After updating your data call a trigger function on the specific cell to access cellEdited():

Javascript

```
cellEdited:function(cell){             
cell.getElement().style.color= "#ffffff";              //CHANGE CELL WHITE FONT
cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#e68a00";   //CHANGE CELL GOLD COLOR
}
```